# How to get the list of message using conversation Id from Microsoft Graph Api

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I need a help on how to find the list of messages using a conversation Id:

So to what i understand, i have explained the scenario below:

1. When a mail is sent we get two important attributes, ID, Conversation Id.
2. So when a reply comes we see that the replied email has a conversation ID same as parent Mail Conversation ID.
3. I have a proper conversation ID, But the issue is that I am currently using Microsoft Graph api library in my spring boot application. Where in I am not sure how to drill down to find list of mails replied using conversation ID.

I tried using the documentation but no luck, as the documentation do not mention any thing about this scenario.

Could some one help me in understanding or please share the link which can be refered to solve the issue.

below is the code i am using to execute the function,

```
mGraphServiceClient.me().messages().buildRequest()
```

So here I can find with ID, but i am not sure from the parent ID how to get its all threads.

Comment: I fixed the bug, we can use $filter to filter by conversationId so by this I was able to resolve it.

Comment: Is the parent message id equal to the conversation id?

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to call api for getting messages from inbox and sent folder.
try like this 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages$select=conversationId,subject,from,body,receivedDateTime,id,hasAttachments,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,replyTo&$filter=conversationId eq 'hugyguder76439cbfnu4f4n'`

Comment: Do you have any idea how can identify the message is replied message?

Comment: @ShaktiS.P.Swain there is a conversationId or replyId for identify the message is replied or not